# Question on substitution when forming a Fourier series of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the given function:

\begin{equation}
    f_n(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j\chi_{A_j}(t)\text{d}t,
\end{equation}

where:

$$\chi_{A_j}(\xi)=\begin{cases}
        2, \ \ \ \ -2\le \xi<-1 \\
        1, \ \ \ \ -1\le \xi<0 \\
        2, \ \ \ \ 0\le \xi<1 \\
        3, \ \ \ \ 1\le \xi\le2
    \end{cases}$$

and I generate its Fourier series as follows:

With $L=\frac{b-a}{2}=2$ and $\omega=\frac{\pi}{L}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Using the substitution $t = \frac{Ly}{\pi} = \frac{2y}{\pi}, \  (-\pi \le t \le \pi)$, we can convert the function above into the function:

\begin{equation}
    F(t)=f\bigg(\frac{2y}{\pi}\bigg)
\end{equation}

By the Fourier series we have therefore:

\begin{equation}
    F(y)=f\bigg(\frac{2y}{\pi}\bigg)=\frac{\alpha_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_k\cos ky+\beta_k\sin ky
\end{equation}

Now at this stage I got confused by that substitution, and I did as follows for the first coefficient:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\alpha_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(y)\text{d}y=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{d}y+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\text{d}y+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{d}y+\frac{3}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\text{d}y=4
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Even though this gives the same result as in Mathematica for that given Series, I am unsure about the coefficients in front of each integral sign.

I can't seem to conclude if they are correct!

Any ideas appreciated

Thanks

Comment: $a_0=\frac{1}{P}\int\limits_{-P/2}^{P/2} f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int\limits_{-2}^{-1} 2\,dx+\int\limits_{-1}^0 1\,dx+\int\limits_0^1 2\,dx+\int\limits_1^2 3\,dx\right)=2$ which is the average value of $f(x)$.

Comment: @StevenClark thanks for this confirmation. Then this OP is correct!